# Android Street View API animateTo issue

Tags: android, google-maps, google-street-view

I'm building an Android application with street view in it. In some cases, I want to set the camera POV manually.

I have looked at the guides [on Google's dev website](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/streetview?hl=en) but I can't seem to get it working.

I am able to show the street view in my app, and I can move the camera around, but it does not move to my custom defined camera/FOV.

My Java code:

```
package com.mycompany.appname;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import java.util.Random;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.*;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.StreetViewPanoramaCamera;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.StreetViewPanoramaOrientation;

public class RaceMap extends FragmentActivity implements OnStreetViewPanoramaReadyCallback {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_race_map);
        StreetViewPanoramaFragment streetViewPanoramaFragment =
                (StreetViewPanoramaFragment) getFragmentManager()
                        .findFragmentById(R.id.streetviewpanorama);
        streetViewPanoramaFragment.getStreetViewPanoramaAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStreetViewPanoramaReady(StreetViewPanorama panorama)  {
        long duration = 20;
        float tilt = 30;
        float bearing = 90;
        StreetViewPanoramaCamera camera = new StreetViewPanoramaCamera.Builder()
                .zoom(panorama.getPanoramaCamera().zoom)
                .bearing(bearing)
                .tilt(tilt)
                .build();

        panorama.setPosition(new LatLng(52.208818, 0.090587));
        panorama.setStreetNamesEnabled(false);
        panorama.setZoomGesturesEnabled(false);
        panorama.animateTo(camera, duration);

    }
}
```

My activity:

```
<fragment
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.mycompany.appname.RaceMap"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.StreetViewPanoramaFragment"
    android:id="@+id/streetviewpanorama"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Comment: You mean, panorama.animateTo() doesn't work?

Comment: Exactly, it doesn't do anything at all. Doesn't throw an error either.

Comment: is my answer correct?

Comment: so? come and close the question

Answer (score 3):

Try to set duration more then 500 millis and you will see what you want. 1 second will be enough.

```
final long duration = 1000;
panorama.animateTo(camera, duration);
```

I think it could be some bug of StreetView. Duration value less then 500 doesn't work correctly. Or maybe map doesn't have enough time to make animation.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into a similar issue, and it seems related to the delay of applying `setPosition()`, which ends up overriding the camera position anim. My solution was to wait till the position change before calling `animTo()`.

And I also agree with @pengrad about very short anim durations

```
@Override
public void onStreetViewPanoramaReady(final StreetViewPanorama panorama)  {
    final long duration = 1000; 
    float tilt = 30;
    float bearing = 90;
    final StreetViewPanoramaCamera camera = new StreetViewPanoramaCamera.Builder()
            .zoom(panorama.getPanoramaCamera().zoom)
            .bearing(bearing)
            .tilt(tilt)
            .build();

    panorama.setPosition(new LatLng(52.208818, 0.090587));
    panorama.setStreetNamesEnabled(false);
    panorama.setZoomGesturesEnabled(false);

    panorama.setOnStreetViewPanoramaChangeListener(new StreetViewPanorama.OnStreetViewPanoramaChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onStreetViewPanoramaChange(StreetViewPanoramaLocation streetViewPanoramaLocation) {
            if (streetViewPanoramaLocation != null) {
                panorama.animateTo(camera, duration);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing `setPosition()` has to take time to find the panorama nearest to the given position.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to move forward just use these two methods:

```
float difference(StreetViewPanoramaLink link) {
        return Math.abs(panorama.getPanoramaCamera().bearing % 360 - link.bearing);
    }


    void moveForward() {
        StreetViewPanoramaLink curLink = null;
        for( int i=0; i < panorama.getLocation().links.length; i++) {
            float differ = difference(panorama.getLocation().links[i]);
            if(curLink == null) {
                curLink = panorama.getLocation().links[i];
            }
            if(difference(curLink) > difference(panorama.getLocation().links[i])) {
                curLink = panorama.getLocation().links[i];
            }
        }
        panorama.setPosition(curLink.panoId);
    }
```